# Floated and Centered Wordpress Page Content

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float, center, margin

SO,

I'm having problems trying to center a series of floating elements on a page. I'm working on a page which uses a few floating elements at the top: a page title, then an image, and then another word from the page title, all floated next to each other in that order.

To achieve that, I'm using:

```
<div class="bodyheaddiv"><p class="bodyheadtext">Contact Us</p><img class="bodyhead"     src="http://lrgi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Contact_icon_1.png" alt="" /><p     class="bodyheadtext">Contáctenos</p></div>​
```

With CSS:

```
.bodyheaddiv {
height: 51px;
width: 500px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.bodyhead {
display: inline;
float: left;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-right: 10px;
position: relative;
}

.bodyheadtext {
line-height: 30px;
display: inline;
clear: none;
float: left;
margin-top: 0px;
font-size: 18px;
position: relative;
}​
```

The result as of now is this:
[image]

Where the page title and image are not centered in their column. *However*, what I'm trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Any help with figuring out how to center these elements on the page would be greatly appreciated!

-Marca

Comment: The HTML is quite a mess... bodyheaddiv is a Container and a Header too... you should have a container, and then inside a header, three columns, a footer etc... 
then you can set text-align: center;
I suggest you to post a JSFiddle with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4VJqh/)**

```
<div>
    <p><span>Contact Us</span><span>Contáctenos</span></p>
</div>​
```

With the CSS:

```
div {
    height: 70px;
    width: 500px;
    0 auto;
    background-image: url('http://lrgi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Contact_icon_1.png');
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div p {
    text-align: center;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

div p span {
    margin: 0 60px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

heres your answer

```
<div class="bodyheaddiv">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>
<p class="bodyheadtext">Contact Us</p></td>
<td><img class="bodyhead"     src="http://lrgi.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Contact_icon_1.png" alt="" /></td>
<td><p class="bodyheadtext">Contáctenos</p></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: This isn't tabular data, so one should not use a `<table>`

Comment: was only giving an alternative